# PHP Fatal error: Class 'PayAssure\Models\User' not found

Tags: php

please l'm seeing this error if a user login to app after uploading my app to server. **domain.com is currently unable to handle this request. http error 500** And everything was working fine in my local xampp server. When i checked my error-log, i saw this

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PayAssure\Models\User' not found in /home/payassur/public_html/dashboard/app/init.php on line 22.

What could have happened? please help.

Below is my init.php code.

```
<?php
session_start();
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

require_once (ABSPATH . "../vendor/autoload.php");

$GLOBALS['config'] = [
    'mysql' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'payassure'
    ]
];
if (!$_SESSION['user_id']) {
    header ("Location: ../index.php");
}
use PayAssure\Models\User;
use PayAssure\Models\Database;
$u = new User;  //this is the line 22
$dd = new Database;
$dbb = $dd->getConnection();

$userIsBlocked = $dbb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id AND 
blocked = '1'");
$userIsBlocked->execute(['user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']]);
if ($userIsBlocked->rowCount() > 0) {
header("Location: userBlocked.php");
}
```

This is the code in models/user

```
<?php
namespace PayAssure\Models;
use PayAssure\Models\Database;

/**
 * @package PayAssure HQ
 */
class User
{

protected $db;
public $errors;

public function __construct()
{
    $d = new Database;
    $this->db = $d->getConnection();
    return $this->db;
}
```

my vendor/autoload

```
  // autoload.php @generated by Composer

 require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

 return ComposerAutoloaderInit3a313f3d3ce53ad02ae8da633a01a1c9::getLoader();
```

my autoload_real.php

```
<?php

// autoload_real.php @generated by Composer

class ComposerAutoloaderInit3a313f3d3ce53ad02ae8da633a01a1c9
{
private static $loader;

public static function loadClassLoader($class)
{
    if ('Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader' === $class) {
        require __DIR__ . '/ClassLoader.php';
    }
}

public static function getLoader()
{
    if (null !== self::$loader) {
        return self::$loader;
    }

spl_autoload_register(array(
'ComposerAutoloaderInit3a313f3d3ce53ad02ae8da633a01a1c9', 
'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
    self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();

spl_autoload_unregister(array(
'ComposerAutoloaderInit3a313f3d3ce53ad02ae8da633a01a1c9', 
'loadClassLoader'));

    $useStaticLoader = PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600 && !defined('HHVM_VERSION');
    if ($useStaticLoader) {
        require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload_static.php';


call_user_func(
 \Composer\Autoload\ComposerStaticInit3a313f3d3ce53ad02ae8da633a01a1c9::
getInitializer($loader));
    } else {
        $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_namespaces.php';
        foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
            $loader->set($namespace, $path);
        }

        $map = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_psr4.php';
        foreach ($map as $namespace => $path) {
            $loader->setPsr4($namespace, $path);
        }

        $classMap = require __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php';
        if ($classMap) {
            $loader->addClassMap($classMap);
        }
    }

    $loader->register(true);

    return $loader;
}
}
```

My composer.json file

```
    {
     "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
          "PayAssure\\": "app/PayAssure"
        }
    },
   "require-dev": {
    "heroku/heroku-buildpack-php": "*",
    "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
  }
}
```

Comment: is your vendor autoload path correct and is it reachable/readable? It's better to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` rather than a relative path as you have.

Comment: you also really should be using `exit;` after `header("Location:...` calls

Comment: yes autoload path is correct

Comment: Nobody has solution to my problem?

Comment: maybe tell us what you've tried yourself to fix it? Tell is the issues you know it isn't (such as you know the file exists?) Do any other files call the same class and work ok?

Comment: Can you also show the composer file where the namespaces are defined?  It could be that the namespace isn't defined correctly, and therefore the autoload can't find the class.

Comment: Yeah the file exist. as u can see it above the line 22 in init.php file. where i use PayAssure/models/User.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use PayAssure\Models\User as user1;
use PayAssure\Models\Database;
$u = new user1;  //this is the line 22
```

Then see still error in 22 no line.

Comment: I saw this error again after including as user1                                        
      PHP Fatal error:  Class 'User' not found in 
     /home/payassur/public_html/dashboard/app/init.php on line 22

Comment: Maybe something is wrong in your base path, please check once 
if(class_exists('pathOfUserClass')){
echo 'exist'
}else{
echo 'notExist';
}

Also i edit my answer, please go with that then check.

Comment: It also give the same error after editing to user1. How do I check?

Comment: i saw exists after i check

Comment: Anyway, the was done for somebody else, but i was licensed to download it and edit it. After editing, everything was working fine in xammp server until after I uploaded it to web server that I started seeing the errors. Maybe there's something I didn't edited right